# Symfony2 + Doctrine2: Is it possible to interact with validation annotations within an Entity setter?

Tags: validation, symfony, annotations, doctrine, entity

I have an [Entity](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html) which i have decorated using validation [annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Entity
{
    /**
     * @Assert\MaxLength(100)
     */
    protected $property;
    ...
}
```

Within the setter for `$property` i want to know if validation was successful of the annotation when a form is submitted. If validation is successful (or not) i will perform other operations in PHP that is not available via the annotations.

Is this possible? i.e.:

```
...
function setProperty($value)
{
    if(annotation_validation_passed_when_form_submitted)
    {
        $value = do_something($value);
    }
    $this->property = $value;
}
...
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Symfony 2.1.3 - Doctrine 2

Comment: You would have to make a Validator accessible either as a class-property or as argument of `setProperty()`, which I would consider messy. Maybe writing a custom ValidationConstraint which triggers an error on `$form->isValid()` would be more helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `EventListener` to your `FormBuilder` to listen for the `FormEvents::BIND` event. You can either do this in its own class or just in the form builder itself. I'll show an example of the latter because it's faster.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::BIND, function($event) {
        $data = $event->getData();

        $comment = $data->getComment();
        $comment = $comment . $comment;
        $data->setComment($comment);
});
```

Of course replace the logic with your own.